# How to get the pre-condition of each test with Jira Rest API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-xray

I am trying to get data about tests of a Jira test execution such as : Summary, assignee, type, status and pre-conditions (the summary to be precised). The problem is I can't get the pre-condition's data.
Of course I can get the pre-condition's key and other stuff but I need the summary column.

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain details about those entities, which are standard Jira issues, you need to use [Jira's REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/8.5.7/#api/2/issue-getIssue) and use the Jira issue key or id.

Example of HTTP GET request:

```
https://sandbox.xpand-it.com/rest/api/2/issue/BOOK-36?fields=summary
```

Response:

```
{
  "expand": "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",
  "id": "20201",
  "self": "https://sandbox.xpand-it.com/rest/api/2/issue/20201",
  "key": "BOOK-36",
  "fields": {
    "summary": "Manual test of strong password validation"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to test management with Jira Xray, following rest api will help in getting all the details for a given pre-condition.

**Rest URL:** `GET /rest/raven/1.0/api/precondition/{preConditionKey}/test`

**Sample Response:**

```
[{
    key: "TEST-1",
    self: "http://localhost:6080/rest/api/2/issue/19701",
    reporter: "admin",
    precondition: [{
        preconditionKey: "TEST-4",
        self: "http://localhost:6080/rest/api/2/issue/19705",
        reporter: "admin",
        type: "Cucumber"
    }],
    type: "Cucumber"
}, {
    key: "TEST-2",
    self: "http://localhost:6080/rest/api/2/issue/19701",
    reporter: "admin",
    precondition: [{
        preconditionKey: "TEST-4",
        self: "http://localhost:6080/rest/api/2/issue/19705",
        reporter: "admin",
        type: "Cucumber"
    }],
    type: "Cucumber"
}]
```

Jira XRAY Api documentation Link: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Pre-Conditions+-+REST